# How to make player move only along the line

Tags: unity, c#

I am using Line Renderer to draw a line on 2D scene using a path of multiple Transforms. And I want player to move along the line without the ability to get off it, like if he was on a rail. The simplest method I can see is setting a number of invisible walls along the line, so the player couldn't physically move away from the line. But maybe there's better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a line with a starting point `pStart` and an end point `pEnd`.

To get any point on a line, use the linear function equation:

```
y = m * x + b
```

Now you have to get the slope of the line which is simply `m = (pEnd.x - pStart.x) / (pEnd.y - pStart.y)`. Then, you can calculate every `x` and `y` pair on the line by simply putting in a value for `x`. So far for the mathematical background, now to the practical implementation (this is all pseudocode).

In your case, you can build a slope vector for the line

```
slopeX = pEnd.x - pStart.x
slopeY = pEnd.y - pStart.y
```

and then normalize it (get it to a lenght of one):

```
slopeLength = squareroot((slopeX * slopeX) + (slopeY * slopeY))
slopeNormX = slopeX / slopeLength
slopeNormY = slopeY / slopeLength
```

Now you know in which direction you have to move your player each time step. To move him, simply do the following:

```
playerX += slopeNormX * deltaTime
playerY += slopeNormY * deltaTime
```

Also, don't forget to check wether the player is still on the line:

```
playerX*playerX > pEnd.x*pEnd.x && playerY*playerY > pEnd.y*pEnd.y
```

We have to square the positions here because we don't know wether the coordinates are positive or negative (`abs()` would be too slow).

Cheers

Comment: Abs is slow. Since we only care which is greater, it should be faster to compare the squares of both numbers (by simple multiplication, not pow).